# Python can't find module named apt_pkg

Tags: 16.04, python3, add-apt-repository

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and on my server I have 2 version of python , python3.5 and python3.6.

What I already tried is:

uninstalling `python3-apt` and reinstalling it, didn't help still the same error.

EDIT: on `python3` I have python3.6 running.

Added error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
```

Comment: try `sudo apt install python-apt`

Comment: @Emmet same thing, I also added the traceback in the post for a better view of the error.

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386097/python-add-apt-repository-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg

Comment: @Emmet for some reasons on python3.5 works fine wierd, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 10):

In my case because I have 2 versions of python installed, python3.5 and python3.6 , the module wasn't found on the python3.6 version so what I did thanks to @Emmet suggestions was:

`nano /usr/bin/add-apt-repository` edited the line `#! /usr/bin/python3` into `#! /usr/bin/python3.5` and now `add-apt-repository` command works again.

Comment: I've updated python from version 3.5 to 3.7 in my ubuntu 16.04 and I faced this issue after that. Your answer solved my issue.

Comment: Great! I had the same issue with identical traceback and your solution has definitely worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that sometimes when you upgrade from an older python version some packages stay in the previous version path, so here is what I did:

`cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

check the existence of a file named `apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` or **34m** or **36m** listing the files and when you find it, delete de current `apt_pkg.so` file

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages# rm apt_pkg.so`

finally create a link with the correct path using `apt_pkg.so` like this:

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages# sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Now you can try again and It should work.